# How to pack external dlls to single file executable

Tags: c#, dll, import

I want to import 2 Gmap dlls to my project, using c# and Visual Studio 15.
But if i run the exe in an other computer or at the desktop nothings happens (exe does not execute like in the VS environment).

Is there a way to add the dlls like the built-in libaries so I can use the exe without carrying the dlls around?

The exe has to run on different laptops without having access to the admin account and without making changes in the Net enviroment on machine. It has to run at the moment the person wants to execute the app at his computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options spring to mind:

**Option 1:** extract modules and all resources from dlls and rebind them to a new assembly using the [Assembly Linker tool (al.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex(v=vs.110).aspx). There also seems to exist a tool which uses this approach - [ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge).

**Option 2:** add those extra dlls (and other files) to your host application as embedded files and load them dynamically. Jeffrey Richter has [an example for this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/).

I would suggest you get a hold of Jeffrey Richter's wonderful book "CLR via C#" which explains what an .Net assembly is and how you can play with it.

EDIT: Jeffrey Richter post also contains a good argument about the difference between these options:

> ILMerge produces a new assembly file from a set of existing assemblies. This means that the original assemblies lose their identity (name, version, culture, and public key).
>
> What I am showing here is creating an assembly that embeds the EXISTING assemblies into it so that they do not lose their identity at all.
>
> Because the original assemblies keep their identity, more scenarios work correctly, such as serialization & security.

Comment: The exe is gonna excecute at difrents hosts. So i guess Option 2 wont work here.

Comment: What do you mean by "different hosts"? that you don't have access to appdomain? If so, please explain your scenario in more detail.

Comment: The exe have to run on diffrent laptops without having access to the admin account or to chance to make some settings in the Net enviroment. It has to run at the moment the person wants to execute the app at his computer.

Comment: In which case I don't see a problem with option2. Appdomain is not a .net environment change, it's the container of logic which is spinned up once user clicks on your exe. In whatever computer. Option 2 instructs that host to look for dlls from within the original assembly.

Comment: in this case i have to look closer to your suggestion. Thanks for your time. I have no experience in this area. I will mark your question as the solution!